# Force user to select data in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

1. Form1 has a button "ADD", on clicking it Form2 pop ups. Form2 has two buttons "OK" and "CANCEL".
2. Form2 has some data to select, user may select the data and press "OK" or click "CANCEL".
3. Without selecting data and pressing OK or clicking cancel button, user may not leave the form. I want to force user either click "OK" or "cancel" button. Only then user can leave Form2.

Please help me to achieve this in vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

A basic idea is to check that the textbox selection length is equal to the textbox's text length in the textbox then have a Boolean variable that if not set prevents the form from closing, something like this.

```
Public Class MyDialog
    Dim closeValid As Boolean
    Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
        If TextBox1.SelectionLength = TextBox1.Text.Length Then
            closeValid = True
            Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        closeValid = True
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyDialog_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If Not closeValid Then e.Cancel = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

Actually a better way would be to intercept the closing reason in the Dialogs FormClosing event and test it against the UserClosing close reason, this way if the application closes or the system shuts down your application will not hang. You can then supply the appropriate CloseReason to the DialogResult and test that when your form returns from your ShowDialog call.

**Form1**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
        Dim form2 As New MyDialog
        Dim dr As DialogResult = form2.ShowDialog()
        If dr = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            'Process your OK
        ElseIf dr = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            'Process your Cancel
        Else
            'Do Something
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form2**

```
Public Class MyDialog
    Private Sub MyDialog_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then e.Cancel = True 'This is true if user clicks the X
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
        If TextBox1.SelectionLength = TextBox1.Text.Length Then
            DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @Prathamesh. I noticed that you unchecked the answer as not answering your question. Is there a problem with the answer that I need to further address?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ShowDialog to open the second form. On the second form, set the DialogResult on button click. Like this:

```
Dim frm2 = new Form2()
If frm2.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK Then
'do something because the user clicked OK

End If
```

Comment: It sounds like he wants to prevent the user from closing the form unless certain conditions are made this will not stop the form from closing

Comment: Good point Mark. I made an assumption on his intentions... when will I learn :)

Comment: It's the form on which he wants to select `OK` or `Cancel`, not a separate `Messagebox`.

Answer (score 0):

1) create a Global function (best in a module so that you only need to declare once)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices                 ' required imports
Public intInputBoxCancel as integer                    ' public variable

Public Function StrPtr(ByVal obj As Object) As Integer
    Dim Handle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    StrPtr = Handle.AddrOfPinnedObject.ToInt32
    Handle.Free()
End Function
```

in the form load event put this (to make the variable intInputBoxCancel = cancel event)

```
intInputBoxCancel = StrPtr(String.Empty)
```

now, you can use anywhere in your form (or project if StrPtr is declared global in module)

```
dim ans as string = inputbox("prompt")         ' default data up to you
if StrPtr(ans) = intInputBoxCancel then
   ' cancel was clicked
else
   ' ok was clicked (blank input box will still be shown here)
endif
```